# link using $_GET whilst using isset cant find page

Tags: php, get, include

Im currently trying to get a link:

```
  <a href='?p=bid?Sale_ID=$Sale_ID'>BID</a>
```

to work but I keep getting a "Page you are requesting doesn´t exist" message, this page works if i use this link:

```
  <a href='include/bid.php?Sale_ID=$Sale_ID'>BID</a>
```

this leads me to believe that my problem lies with the isset im using to include pages on link:

```
  <?php
  if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] != "") {
  $p = $_GET['p'];
  if (file_exists('include/'.$p.'.php')) {
  @include ('include/'.$p.'.php');
  } elseif (!file_exists('include/'.$p.'.php')) {
  echo 'Page you are requesting doesn´t exist<br><br>';
  }
  } else {
  @include ('include/login-form.php');
  }
  ?>
```

Ive tried adding another isset replacing p with q which just throws my pages in to dissaray.

So my question is, is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you checking for the file's existence twice? It's easier, and faster, to just do it as an else rather than an else if. If it didn't find it existing the first time, it wont find it the second, and what do you do if it DOES find it the second time? Unlikely/impossible, but should it happen, your code breaks, so easier to just go if...else in your case, not if...elseif...else.

Comment: Stop using the error suppressor operator `@` -- really... never use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two question marks here:

`?p=bid?Sale_ID=$Sale_ID`

Multiple querystring parameters are separated by ampersand:

`?p=bid&Sale_ID=$Sale_ID`

Answer (score 1):

The query string you show: `?p=bid?Sale_ID=$Sale_ID` is not valid. The structure of a URL with a string is:

```
filename.extension?first_parameter=first_value&second_parameter=second_value
```

So, if you want `p` to indicate which page:

```
?p=bid&Sale_ID=$Sale_ID
```

.. use the ampersand (`&`) to separate your query string values.

Also, please note that the approach you are using to include a file is insecure. What if I sent this:

```
?p=../../.htpasswd&Sale_ID=0
```

An attacker could use this method to output the contents of files that you do not wish to expose to the public. Make sure you are checking the value of this variable more carefully before blinding including the file.

I also wants to warn you against using the error suppressor (`@`). Errors are your friends! You want to know exactly what happens in your code, using the error suppressor prevents critical problems from being brought to your attention. Really -- never, ever use the error suppressor. Instead of `@include`, use `include`

I suggest something more like this:

```
$file_exists = false;
$page = false;
if (
    isset($_GET['p']) && 
    strlen(trim($_GET['p'])) > 0
){
    $page = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/", "", $_GET['p']);
    $page = str_replace(" ", "-", $page);

    $file_exists = file_exists('include/'.$page.'.php');

    if ($file_exists) {
        include ('include/'.$page.'.php');
    } else {
        $page = false;
        echo 'Page you are requesting doesn´t exist<br><br>';
    }
}
if (!$file_exists ||$page === false)
    include ('include/login-form.php');
```

The first part of the code ensures that the query string value exists and has some content. Then it cleans out any non-alphanumeric characters (this helps prevent exploitation). Then, we check to see if it exists, storing that result in a variable so we can use it again.

If the page exists, the file is included. If not, a "page not found" message is output, and the login form file is included. If no page is specified in the query string, the login form file is included.

**Documentation**

- `$_GET` - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
- Query string on Wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string
- *Exploiting PHP File Inclusion* - an article about security when using `include` and `$_GET` - http://websec.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/exploiting-php-file-inclusion-overview/
- `preg_replace` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
- `str_replace` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

?p=bid "redirects" to your default file, usually index.php. You want it to work in bid.php.

You can set the default file in apache with: 
`DirectoryIndex index.php bid.php`

The other problem is you use multiple ? signs.

`?p=bid&Sale_ID=$Sale_ID` would work a lot better

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that file_exists does not use the include path, so you should be doing this:

```
if (file_exists( get_include_path() . 'include/'.$p.'.php')) {
```

More info:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php